# How do I change the default icon for native dialog mac using Tauri?

Tags: rust, tauri

how do I change the default folder icon for the native dialog on Mac? I went through the [Tauri dialog documentation](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/dialog/), but I could not find any information.

This is my current preview:

[image]

Comment: You should probably add how you're creating this dialog. You might need to add custom css to change the icon.

Comment: But there are no options, such as adding custom CSS here:https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/dialog/

Comment: I found something, but if I understood this correctly, it's for Windows, I think: https://tauri.app/v1/api/config/#wixconfig.dialogimagepath